# Set an office theme to a powerpoint VBA

Tags: vba, themes, powerpoint

I'm currently making an automatic Powerpoint from excel using vba and I would like to set a theme to the document, the "Ion" theme to be precise. I have the following code:

```
Sub CreateFullPres()

Dim ppt As PowerPoint.Application
Dim pres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim sld As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim shp2 As Shape


'Create Powerpoint
Set ppt = New PowerPoint.Application
Set pres = ppt.Presentations.Add
ppt.Visible = True


'Add Slide
Set Slide1 = pres.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutTitle).Shapes.Placeholders
SlideTitle = Sheets("FIBO Monthly Update").Range("B4")
SubTitle1 = Sheets("FIBO Monthly Update").Range("B6")
SubTitle2 = Sheets("FIBO Monthly Update").Range("B7")
Slide1.Item(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = SlideTitle
Slide1.Item(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = SubTitle1 & ": " & SubTitle2
```

The code continues after this but this is all that is necessary.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pres.ApplyTheme {full path to your thmx file}

Finding the MS-supplied themes can be tricky. It'll be simpler if you create a presentation based on the Ion theme, save it as a THMX to a convenient location, then specify that path/file.thmx in the code above.

By the way, you'll also want to use

```
Dim shp2 As PowerPoint.Shape
```

instead of

```
Dim shp2 As Shape
```

which dims it as an Excel shape rather than a PowerPoint shape; they're likely to have different properties.